# Is there in literature a descriptive abbreviation phrase for "for infinitely many $n$"?

Tags: soft-question, notation, terminology

Let $P(n)$ be a property for all $n \geq 1$. For the phrase "there is some $N \geq 1$ such that $P(n)$ holds for all $n \geq N$" there are some suggestive, convenient abbreviations such as "$P(n)$ holds for large $n$" or "$P(n)$ holds eventually" and so on.

I wonder if there is in literature a like abbreviation for "$P(n)$ holds for infinitely many $n$"? I am aware that in probability theory some authors would write "$P(n)$ holds infinitely often"; but, in my humble opinion, this abbreviation would be not that useful in contexts other than probability theory.

Comment: Almost all is sometimes used in this context. But one must be very careful not to confuse this with something else.

Comment: @SamM that's not used for "infinitely often" but for "all but finitely many" which is mentioned at the start but not what the question is about.

Comment: @SamM Oh, thanks. I think I pre-sieved out this case; I saw in some older stuff that some authors use "almost all" for "eventually". Besides, "almost all" may cause confusion in measure-theoretic contexts.

Comment: when you're dealing with $\Bbb N$, eventually and almost all mean the same thing. But it might not be the case in other contexts.

Comment: @GudsonChou it is *never* used just to say infinitely many. There is a confusion with that comment. It'd be absurd to say the powers of two are "almost all" integers.

Comment: @quid Thank you; I was not sure about that.

Comment: @quid you are quite right, apologies. I have used "holds infinitely often" before, but, as above, this is somewhat different.

Comment: In probability theory, "infinitely often" is often (infinitely so?) abbreviated "i.o.".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [John L. Kelley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_L._Kelley)'s *General Topology* (available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/GeneralTopology)), p. 65:

> A **directed set** is a pair $(D,\ge)$ such that $\ge$ directs $D.$ [. . . .] A net $\{S_n,n\in D,\ge\}$ is **in** a set $A$ iff $S_n\in A$ for all $n$; it is **eventually in** $A$ iff there is an element $m$ of $D$ such that, if $n\in D$ and $n\ge m,$ then $S_n\in A.$ The net is **frequently in** $A$ iff for each $m$ in $D$ there is $n$ in $D$ such that $n\ge m$ and $S_n\in A.$

Similarly, I guess you could say "$P(n)$ holds **eventually**" if $P(n)$ holds for all sufficiently large $n,$ and "$P(n)$ holds **frequently**" if $P(n)$ holds for infinitely many $n.$

Answer (score 5):

In descriptive set theory and logic one sometimes uses $\exists^\ast_n P(n)$ for "there are infinitely many $n$ such that $P(n)$ holds", and $\forall^\ast_n P(n)$ for "all but finitely many $n$ satisfy $P(n)$".

Then at least we have $\lnot \forall^\ast_n P(n) \leftrightarrow \exists^\ast_n \lnot P(n)$, like for normal quantifiers, e.g.

Comment: Thank you. I think I prefer literal phrases instead of symbolic phrases.

Answer (score 3):

In some contexts (set theory, order theory, point set topology, though probably never in probability) you can say *cofinally*, or *cofinally many*, *cofinally often*. Given a preorder $(A,\preceq)$, a subset $X\subseteq A$ is *cofinal* in $A \Leftrightarrow$ for every $a\in A$ there is $x\in X$ with $a\preceq x$. A predicate $\varphi(x)$ holds *cofinally often*, and is true for *cofinally many* $x$, iff $\{x\in A\mid \varphi(x)\}$ is cofinal in $A$. For $\Bbb N$ with the usual order, this is exactly the same notion as "infinitely often".

"Eventually" is often used in such a setting (vis a vis a preorder) to mean: $eventually_x, \varphi(x) \!\stackrel{def}\iff\!$ there is $a\in A$ such that for all $x\succeq a, \varphi(x)$. In that case, "frequently" can be and has been used rather than "cofinally often".

Note that these two notions are quantifiers, duals of each other:
$$
\text{frequently$_x \varphi(x) \iff \neg$ eventually$_x \neg\, \varphi(x)$. }
$$
In his book [General Topology](https://ia600501.us.archive.org/16/items/GeneralTopology/Kelley-GeneralTopology.pdf) [p.65], Kelley uses the terms "eventually" and "frequently", for special cases of these notions: given a directed preorder $(A,\preceq)$, a function $f\colon A\to B$ is *frequently* in a subset $Y\subseteq B$ *iff* $\{x\in A\mid f(x)\in Y\}$ is cofinal in $A$. Similarly for the dual notion "$f$ is *eventually* in *Y*". A net $f$ *converges* to a point $b\in B \!\iff\!$ for every neighborhood $U$ of $b$, $f$ is eventually in $U$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm aware of only one way how to write this clearly -- in symbols:

$$ \exists_\infty n\in\mathbb{N} : P(n). $$

However, unless you need this a lot you shouldn't use this notation. If you need it a lot, you can introduce it:

> We suppose that $P(n)$ holds for infinitely many $n$, i.e., that $\exists_\infty n\in\mathbb{N}:P(n)$.

Some people use: "$P(n)$ holds infinitely many times," but I don't find this one quite nice; also, it's not even shorter. In contexts when no confusion can happen, one can use: "$P(n)$ holds infinitely often." However, be aware that to some, this means that $P(n)$ holds with a positive density.